# chmod command in data pump directory not working second time using Java code deployed on oracle weblogic server

Tags: java, oracle, unix

I am trying to create dmp file of a table A_LOCKER using expdp cmd and then sftp it back to local machine on which my java code is deployed.The server is an oracle weblogic server.
The code is working fine for first time but from second time it is giving error as:Permission denied

The dmp file is created in a data pump directory Extract which is create by me.

Now i try to sftp the dmp file and for that i need to provide sudo permission for the file 
so i tried following in my java code:
1)To create session:

```
    StringBuffer cmd = new StringBuffer();        

    FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = null;

    SshClient ssh = new SshClient();
    SessionChannelClient session = null;
    SftpClient sftp = null;


    HostKeyVerification host = new IgnoreHostKeyVerification();

    // Try to connect to the machine that includes the shared folder
    // Throw an exception when a connection is failed.
    try {
        ssh.connect(machine, host);
    } catch (IOException e) {


        logger.error("Cannot connect to dbserver in machine "
                        + machine,e);
        throw new EPCShareFileException(
                "Cannot connect to dbserver location in machine "
                        + machine, e);
    }


    PasswordAuthenticationClient auth = new PasswordAuthenticationClient();
    auth.setUsername(user);
    auth.setPassword(password);
    // Authenticate user name and password for connection
    // Throw an exception if authentication is failed

    try {
        ssh.authenticate(auth);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        logger.error("Cannot authenticate user "
                + user + " " + " password " + password);
        ssh.disconnect();

        throw new EPCShareFileException("Cannot authenticate user "
                + user + " " + " password " + password, e);
    }
```

2)Execute chmod command using pseudo permission

```
                  cmd.append("/usr/local/bin/sudo /bin/chmod -R 777 ")
                     .append(location+dbDumpFileName);
                   try{
        session = ssh.openSessionChannel();
        session.executeCommand(cmd.toString());

    } catch (IOException e){
        logger.error("Cannot execute chmod cmd");
    } 
    finally{
        try {
            session.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            logger.info("Cannot close the session:"+e.getMessage());
        }

    }
```

3)Then i am trying to sftp the dmp file to local server

```
                   try {
        sftp = ssh.openSftpClient();
        } catch (IOException e) {
        logger.error("Cannot open connection to database server");
        ssh.disconnect();
        throw new EPCShareFileException(
                "Cannot open connection to database server");

    }

    try{
        fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(dbDumpFileName);

        sftp.get(location+dbDumpFileName, fileOutputStream);
    }catch (IOException e) {
        **throw new EPCShareFileException("Cannot retrive file "
                +"Error:"+e.getMessage());**
    }finally{
        try {
            fileOutputStream.close();
            sftp.quit();
            fileOutputStream = null;
            sftp = null;

        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        ssh.disconnect();
        ssh = null;
    }
```

For first time when i am deploying my code as ear file on oracle weblogic server it is working file and dmp file is created and sftped to desired location as well
But from second time i am getting error: 
                 **Error:Permission denied**

Please Help..

Comment: Is the `permission denied` error coming from trying to read the file on the Oracle server, or write it on the local machine? What permissions does the local file have after the first `get`? (Unless you're deleting it before the second attempt, of course...)

Comment: .exception.ShareFileException: Cannot retrive file Extract20140408174212.dmp from /userhome/home/user/myuser/Extract/Error:Permission denied java.io.IOException: Permission denied The error is in following code: try{ fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(dbDumpFileName); sftp.get(location+dbDumpFileName, fileOutputStream); }catch (IOException e) { throw new EPCShareFileException("Cannot retrive file " + dbDumpFileName + " from " + location+"Error:"+e.getMessage()+e.toString()); } I checked the created dmp file on unix server and it has rwx permission

Comment: Please add things like that to the question and format them so they are easier to read. You still haven't said if (or how) you're sure the error is from the server and not your local machine, or what permissions the file gets on the local machine after the first transfer. Are `location` and `dbDumpFileName` still set correctly on the second attempt, and is the `FileOutputStream` trying to open the file in the same place locally each time?

Comment: I am using timestamp to append in the filename and i can still see the new files at oracle database server each time i run the job.
I can even transfer them from there manually.
The error:java.io.IOException: Permission denied
is comming from the catch block which i used to handle sftp.get() cmd. thats all i can investigate.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, don't ever use `chmod -R 777` - that's like publishing your data for anyone with access to the machine, no questions asked. If you used this to debug the issue, then okay, but don't forget to change it back (or get rid of it; you shouldn't need it at all).

To debug "Permission denied" errors, you need to have access to the machine. On the machine, you need to login as the user that got the error (don't try as root or another user).

As this user, try to access every folder in the path that you couldn't access. So if it failed for `/srv/www/foo/bar/x/y/z/file.txt`, then you need to

```
ls /srv
ls /srv/www/
ls /srv/www/foo/
ls /srv/www/foo/bar/
ls /srv/www/foo/bar/x/
ls /srv/www/foo/bar/x/y/
ls /srv/www/foo/bar/x/y/z/
ls /srv/www/foo/bar/x/y/z/file.txt
```

Do it in this order. Find the first command that failed and then check why this user doesn't have permissions for the folder in question.

Comment: `chmod 777` is worse than just "publishing" the data for everyone (i.e. allowing them to read it) - every user is also able to modify or delete it.

Comment: I am trying it for debugging only
by executing above commands i am able to access all directories till the location of my file

Comment: Include the value of `location+dbDumpFileName` in the error message to make sure you're working on the correct file.

Comment: What happens when you do the same thing manually (i.e. not using Java)? Also make sure that the variable `user` contains the value which you expect.

Comment: I included the location and filename

Comment: I included the location and filename Error is exception.EPCShareFileException: Cannot retrive file filename.dmp from /userhome/home/user/tksint/Extract/Error:Permission denied
I modify my code to check if chmod cmd is working fine
try{ session = ssh.openSessionChannel();
boolean status=session.executeCommand(cmd.toString());
if(status==true){
logger.info("Command Executed to grant permission");
}else{
logger.info("Permission Denied");
}
} catch (IOException e){
logger.error("Cannot execute chmod cmd");
  } 
it is returning true i.e Command Executed to grant permission

Comment: the problem is in below code:
try{
   fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(dbDumpFileName);
   
   sftp.get(location+dbDumpFileName, fileOutputStream);
   
   
  }catch (IOException e) {
   throw new EPCShareFileException("Cannot retrive file "
     + dbDumpFileName + " from " + location+"Error:"+e.getMessage()+e.toString());
  }finally{
   try {
    fileOutputStream.close();
    sftp.quit();
    fileOutputStream = null;
    sftp = null;
    
   } catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
   }
   
   ssh.disconnect();
   ssh = null;
  }

Comment: A new dmp file is created everytime i run the job and it works fine for the first time after deploying it on weblogic server.
But from second attemp it is throwing error

Comment: Sftp the file is working fine.
The attribute of the file is set to 777. 
Its the code in which i am getting the error.

Comment: In that case, there must be a difference when you do it manually and when your code does it. Find that difference. Also: Which method does throw the IOException? Is it `new FileOutputStream` or `sftp.get()`?

Comment: sftp.get() method...i am closing and setting each variables used here to null at the end...still is there any possibility that value in the variables are persisting and causing the error?

Comment: Not likely. If you really get "permission denied" from the server, then this means there is an error on the remote side. Local variables are not likely to have an effect on that. Can you enable more logging for the SSH server on the remote side to see why it returns an error?

Comment: .exception.ShareFileException: Cannot retrive file Extract20140408174212.dmp from /userhome/home/user/myuser/Extract/Error:Permission denied java.io.IOException: Permission denied
The error is in following code:
   try{
 fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(dbDumpFileName);
 sftp.get(location+dbDumpFileName, fileOutputStream);
       }catch (IOException e) {
  throw new EPCShareFileException("Cannot retrive file "
  + dbDumpFileName + " from "                        + location+"Error:"+e.getMessage()+e.toString());
  }

I checked the created dmp file on unix server and it has rwx permission

Comment: Also why is it working for the first time i am deploying the .ear on server
It works everytime I redeploy the same code but only once

Comment: If that was Windows, I'd say the file was still open. You need to enable logging on the **server** so you can see which commands the SSH **server** is receiving from the client. Also check the error logs in the Unix server; maybe that gives you an idea what is going on.

Comment: I don't have privileges to check logs on oracale server.I did checked it on my application server and there is no related error.
I created seprate SSH sessions one for executing the chmod cmd and another for Sftp the file.Now it is working fine.But still i dont know the reason.Why can't we execute and sftp in one session and if was the issue why it was successful for first execution earlier.

Comment: Someone has privileges to look at the log files. Find that person and ask for help. There is nothing you can to on the client side to find out why this happens.